# Android Studio how to perform search in .class files?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio how to search in `.class` files inside a directory/project files. I am trying `Ctrl + Shift + F` but it is skipping `.class` files.

Answer (score 0):

try ctrl + F, without Shift
if this doesn't solve the problem, i dont know

Comment: I don't know which file to search, that's why need whole project search.